# What is faster copying or cloning a FreeBSD partition?

Tags: filesystems, copy, clone, freebsd

We faced the issue that there's no space left in the one of the FreeBSD partition. So we decided to get a new disk and mount it instead of the old one. So my question is what is faster to copy the partition content using standard cp or to clone using some other tool?
The file system of the partition is UFS.

Comment: This got hammered on Server Fault as it's a polling question, but X-Istence's answer below is the most generally useful one for this kind of thing: dump & restore will let you restore to a larger partition faster than `cp` and other file-based backup tools, and without as many hoops as `dd` or other raw-disk tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `dump`/`restore`. They are purpose built tools that will copy the files over perfectly whereas `cp` may or may not depending on the flags you give it miss setting attributes/ownership properly.